# Clearing floats dynamically with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a 3-column blog layout in CSS. For each new post, there will be a new div added dynamically inside of a container div.

However, I'm running into trouble with clearing floats since I can't place a clear element manually.

Here's what it looks like now: http://jsfiddle.net/DZASD/

And here's what I want it to look like: http://jsfiddle.net/DZASD/1/

I want to be able to do that without manually placing the `<div style="clear:both;">` after the 3rd div. Is there some way to selectively clear the floating elements after every 3rd div, even if there are potentially infinite divs to be added?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the css selector [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) to apply `clear` to each third element.

**CSS**

```
.box:nth-child(3n + 1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DZASD/5/)**

[How `nth-child` works](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

Note: `nth-child` is [not supported by IE8 and less](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3).